# ugly nested forEach in javascript best practise

Tags: javascript, foreach

Hi my code feels very hacky, i could do the same with forloop which would be better for performance but it will look even more horrible. Is there a cleaner/best practise way of doing this?

this is my datamodel

```
this.data = [
  {
    title: 'Math',
    img: this.mathImage,
    children: [
      {
        title: 'Calculus I & II',
        open: false,
        children: [
          {
            title: 'Differentials',
            open: false,
            children: [
              {
                title: 'Integration by parts',
                key: 'Differentials1',
                mainsub: 'Math',
                middlesub: 'Calculus I & II',
                lowsub: 'Differentials',
                saved: true // <--------------- HERE IS THE PROPERTY
              },
              {
                title: 'Integration by parts',
                key: 'Differentials2',
                mainsub: 'Math',
                middlesub: 'Calculus I & II',
                lowsub: 'Differentials',
                saved: true,
              },
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

this is my code that sets the 'saved' property to false

```
removeFromFavoritesinSubjects(item) {
  this.data.forEach(list => {
    if (list.title === item.mainsub) {
      list.children.forEach(subitem => {
        if (subitem.title === item.middlesub) {
          subitem.children.forEach(items => {
            if (items.title === item.lowsub) {
              items.children.forEach(i => {
                if (i.key === item.key) {
                  i.saved = false;
                }
              })
            }
          })
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: If it's just one property, you could use a chained dot notation, but I suspect there are multiple properties or you need to conduct some kind of search. If so, can you specify exactly what you're searching on (e.g. `key` matches `Differentials1`)?

Comment: You can use filter and map methods

Comment: When do you call this function? If you have a button, you could pass the indexes of the clicked item to the function, and then you don’t need the forEach loops at all. For example : `removeSaved(main, sub){list.children[main].children[sub].saved = false}`

Comment: Note : the children are in arrays which prevents dot notation from being used here.  Same with filter/map, you're going to have to nest those.

Comment: @ggorlen it's just one property in this case. Never worked with chained dot notation, going to try it!

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha would it look better? Think it's more the same?

Comment: @Kokodoko tried it but it won't work, can it work? the mainsub, middlesub properties are strings and not an index to be used inside an array (children) right?

Comment: @Graham oh.. hmm good to know..

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible to simplify, of course.  Just not using those methods.

Comment: @Samvanbeastlo I assumed your data was already visible in your app, because it looks like a menu that can have open/closed states. So when you create the menu, you know the numbered index of each item. That's why I would like to know when exactly the `removeFromFavoritesinSubjects()` function is being called in your code? Most likely you won't need any kind of `for of(), map() or filter()` at all :)

Comment: @Samvanbeastlo additionally, you don't need your keys to store the name of their parents' key... You can use the name of a child's parent directly. That would remove a lot of unnecessary data from your model. Finally, it's questionable if the `saved` state really belongs in a data model... isn't it just the state of your UI? What exactly is `saved` ? Sorry for the long comment!

Comment: @Kokodoko thanks for the response. I store items from the dataobject into localstorage. Once it's in localstorage it becomes an objectarray, when that happens I can't change the data directly from the UI, at that point I need to use this function. 'Saved' is when an item is moved to the localstorage. The original objectitem changes to 'saved' and the new object array gets a new item added to the array. I need this function when someone wants to remove an item from the localstorage objectarray (which is not coupled to the original object) thats why I took this route, hope it makes sense ;-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you only want to change saved to false when you're at the lowest level (i.e. there are no saved properties at other levels).

This answer uses [for... of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to loop through the arrays recursively.

```
function changeSaved(data, key, value) {

  // loop through every object in the array
  for(var element in data){

    // see if there is a children node
    if(element.children){

      // run this function recursively on the children array
      changeSaved(element.children);

    } else {

      // no children key, set the value
      element[key] = value;
    }

  }

}
```

You would call it like this:

```
changeSaved(data, 'saved', 'false');
```

Comment: even cleaner! great i'll change it to the accepted awnser

Answer (score 0):

Searching a data structure linearly is very inefficient, if you have to do this more often you should either store a direct reference to the object in `item` or use a data structure that allows efficient lookup by key (e.g. a `Map`).

Instead of nested loops (that would be better with `for … of` than `.forEach()`) I would use chained [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) invocations though:

```
removeFromFavoritesinSubjects(item) {
  const list = this.data.find(list => list.title === item.mainsub);
  if (!list) return;
  const subitem = list.children.find(subitem => subitem.title === item.middlesub);
  if (!subitem) return;
  const items = subitem.children.find(items => items.title === item.lowsub);
  if (!items) return;
  const i = items.children.find(i => i.key === item.key);
  if (!i) return;
  i.saved = false;
}
```

(Assuming that there are no duplicates in the array, and each `removeFromFavouritesInSubjects()` call sets at most one `.saved` property).

Comment: Much better and the assumptions are correct, i accept this answer. thanks!

Comment: That's what I was thinking to. I suggested filter and map because find only looks for the first element while with filter you get all the elements that satisfies the condition.

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha I don't understand why you'd use `map` though. What result do you want to map to?

Comment: `map` will be used in the last statement when you change the saved attribute to false.

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha But why? I don't want to create a new array

Comment: If you use `filter` you have to deal with arrays anyway, `find` will only return the first value from the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of recursion and `.reduce` function to flatten your data model first and then do what should be done with your flat data model easily.

```
// flattenArray helper function turns nested array into flat array
function flattenArray (array) {
  return array.reduce((result, item) =>
    result.concat([ item ], flattenArray(item.children || []))
  , []);
}

// later in code
{
  // ...
  removeFromFavoritesInSubjects ({ key }) {
    // Consider all children are alongside with each other
    // [..., { title: 'Calculus I & II', ... }, { title: 'Differentials', ... }, ...]
    flattenArray(this.data).forEach(item => {
      if (item.key === key) {
        item.saved = false;
      }
    });
  }
  // ...
}
```

Also don't worry too much about performance to use `for..loop` against `forEach`.